# What's wrong with this jQuery accordion code?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#accordion').accordion();
        });
    </script>

    <body>

        <ul id="accordion">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Header 1</a>
        <div>Wow, look at all this content that can be shown or hidden with a simple click!</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Header 2</a>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin. Sed interdum pulvinar justo. Nam iaculis volutpatligula. Integer  
        vitae felis quis diam laoreet ullamcorper. Etiam tincidunt est vitae est. Ut posuere, mauris at sodales rutrum, turpis tellus fermentum metus, ut      
        bibendum velit enim eu lectus. Suspendisse potenti. </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Header 3</a>
        <div>Donec at dolor ac metus pharetra aliquam. Suspendisse purus. Fusce tempor ultrices libero. Sed quis nunc. Pellentesque tincidunt viverra felis.  
        Integer elit mauris, egestas ultricies, gravida vitae, feugiat a, tellus.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code returns the first image, how do I make it to be like the second image? The styling doesn't matter though, I only want the tabs to be properly aligned like the second image

First image -> [image]

Second image -> [image]

Comment: @mVChr I've no idea how to, please help me here... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accordian works fine. You just need some CSS.

```
ul {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #00f; }
li a { 
    padding: 5px;
    background: #00f; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: center; 
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none; }
 li div { padding: 20px; }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAjSW/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style and the tabs will appear as you desired...

```
<style>
#accordion li {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/yFeuJ/